# prog.java and prog.class in Prog.jar file - How can I easily update this code?

Tags: java, class, jar

**Back story:**
Long ago, before dinosaurs were around, there was a contractor that wrote a small Java program, that does some stuff, and prints some stuff to the screen.

**Current:** No one here knows much about Java but me - and I am *not* fluent.

The program works, but we kind of need just a bit more information on the screen. From the documentation available, I think I know how to go about that, and I definitely know how to print stuff, as it's simply using `System.out.println()` for this.

I have a `.jar` file, which I'm 99% certain is being loaded/used, which contains `.java` files matching every `.class` file within.

**Is there an easy way to (and how might I) slightly modify one of the `.java` files, and "compile" the new version to replace the current matching `.class` file within the `.jar`?**

I'm able to open and read the java source file, of course, but don't remember to procedures to turn java into "class" files, and especially not sure if I can just drop the resulting `.class` file into the `.jar` file as a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the basic level, javac is the compiler; that will produce the .class files.  There is also a "jar" command that will regenerate your jar file.  Depending on the number of dependencies, that can get complicated quick.  You can just type "javac" and "jar" (w/o quotes) to get the args to run it.  Another option is to setup an ant build script...

so you could do something like (assuming windows OS):

javac -cp %MY_CLS_PTH% *.java
  where MY_CLS_PTH is where any dependent classes are.  If you have a package structure, this gets a little more complicated.

jar -cvf .\my_class_dir MyJarFile.jar
  where my_class_dir is the directory that contains the .class files.

I think that is right (didn't run it myself) but that should be about the basics...

EDIT: There is a way to just add/re-add a single .class file to an existing jar file.  Check out the "jar" command's usage, looks like "-u" will update it (of course you have to pass in the .class file).  Also remember that any package structure you have in these classes, you need that directory structure and you reference the class via that dir structure. (Hope that is clear...)

Comment: Aside from possible dependency issues when trying to run `javac` on my source.java file, can the resulting prog.class file be "dropped into" the existing jar file?

Comment: See above as I just added that!

Comment: Might I suggest though that if this is something you are going to be doing "a lot", you might consider setting it up in Netbeans or Eclipse or writing an ant script for it.  Apache has lots of template scripts though you would need to download ant...

Comment: Merky, I agree, but this should be a one off, until I can get set up proper. I'll try out our answer shortly.

Comment: I had to put the existing `.jar` file on the classpath when using the `javac` command. In my case, I opened the `.jar` file with 7zip, and simply replaced the existing `.class` file with the new one. This worked just fine. I have seen the notes saying that this can be done with the `jar` command, but wanted to mention that this way worked for me, as well.

Comment: Assume!  Yea a jar file is a bit of an over-glorified zip file so that works also.  Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

**Add *myclass.class* to the top level directory in *myjar.jar*:**

```
jar uf myjar.jar myclass.class
```

**Add *myclass.class* to the *subdir* directory in *myjar.jar*:**

```
jar uf myjar.jar -C subdir myclass.class
```

**Add a *Version* attribute to the manifest of *myjar.jar*:**

First create a file *somefile* containing the line `Version: "X.Y.Z"`, then

```
jar umf somefile myjar.jar
```